# Задать прозрачность setAlpha только у родителя

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь сделать прозрачным фон `LinearLayout` и при этом текст не должен быть прозрачным.

Делаю так:

```
linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.potehki1); 
linearLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
```

однако,у меня фон и текст становятся прозрачными,а нужно только фон.

Разметка:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/potehki1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/food"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/eda"
            android:id="@+id/eda_text"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"

             />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Пример: фон кнопок прозрачный, а текст нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так вам надо фон бекграунда сделать полупрозрачным кнопки? Если кнопки, то где вы сеттите альфу ей?

Comment: @ Андроид Андроид
картинка только прмиер,У меня совсем дургое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно запихнуть в `FrameLayout` всё это и поставить альфу только на фон:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/food"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/background1" />

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/potehki1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/food"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
        <TextView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/eda"
            android:id="@+id/eda_text"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"

             />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>    
</FrameLayout>
```

Теперь выставим альфу только для фона:

```
linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.background1); 
linearLayout.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
```

Comment: imageViewpot=(ImageView)findViewById (R.id.potbacground);
      imageViewpot.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
ибо background1 относиться же к разметке linearLayou

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто цвет фона устанаваить с прозрачностью и тогда будет как надо

```
#A6000000 - где А6 прозрачность
```